# Concatenate array elements by groups of 3?

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
strings = %w(John likes Pie Diana prefers Cupcakes)
```

Which will look like:

```
strings[0] -> "John"
strings[1] -> "likes"
strings[2] -> "Pie"
strings[3] -> "Diana"
strings[4] -> "prefers"
strings[5] -> "Cupcakes"
```

How can I transform it into this?

```
strings[0] -> "John likes Pie"
strings[1] -> "Diana prefers Cupcakes"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
strings = strings.each_slice(3).map{|a| a.join(" ")}
```

Comment: Could you be kind and walk me through what you're doing here?

Comment: Try `p strings.each_slice(3)`, then `strings.each_slice(3).each{|a| p a}`. The method `p` is the tool when you want to see what is happening.

Comment: Or, maybe `p strings.each_slice(3).to_a`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears (note highlighting in question) that verbs are lowercase and everything else is uppercase.  Assuming that is the case*, and that the subject (`'John'`) and verb  (`'likes'`) are always a single word, and only the first word of the object  (`'Apple pie'`) is capitalized, this should work:

```
def pull_substrings(strings)
  (strings.each_with_index
          .select { |w,_| w[0] =~ /[a-z]/ }
          .map { |_,i| i-1 } << strings.size)
          .each_cons(2).map { |f,lp1| strings[f...lp1].join(' ') }
end
```

Let's try it:

```
strings = %w[John likes Hot Dogs Diana prefers Cupcakes ] +
          %w[Billy-Bob devourers Hot Dogs Chips And Beer]
  #=> ["John", "likes", "Hot", "Dogs",
  #    "Diana", "prefers", "Cupcakes",
  #    "Billy-Bob", "devourers", "Hot", "Dogs", "Chips", "And", "Beer"]

pull_substrings(strings)
  #=> ["John likes Hot Dogs", "Diana prefers Cupcakes",
  #    "Billy-Bob devourers Hot Dogs Chips And Beer"]
```

Here's what's going on with the above array `strings`:

```
# Save each word with its index
a = strings.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ...>
  a.to_a #=> [["John", 0], ["likes", 1], ["Hot", 2], ["Dogs", 3],
         #    ["Diana", 4], ["prefers", 5], ["Cupcakes", 6],
         #    ["Billy-Bob", 7], ["devourers", 8], ["Hot", 9], ["Dogs", 10],
         #      ["Chips", 11], ["And", 12], ["Beer", 13]]

# Locate the positions of the verbs    
b = a.select { |w,_| w[0] =~ /[a-z]/ }
  #=> [["likes", 1], ["prefers", 5], ["devourers", 8]]

# Convert to the locations of the subjects (offsets where strings begin)    
c = b.map { |_,i| i-1 }
  #=> [0, 4, 7]

# Add the position of the last word of the last substring plus 1    
d = c << strings.size
  #=> [0, 4, 7, 14]

# Look at each pair of subject offsets      
e = (d).each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ...>
  e.to_a #=> [[0, 4], [4, 7], [7, 14]]

# Map each pair of offsets to a substring       
e.map { |f,lp1| strings[f...lp1].join(' ') }
  #=> ["John likes Hot Dogs",
  #    "Diana prefers Cupcakes",
  #    "Billy-Bob devourers Hot Dogs Chips And Beer"]
```

The first element of `e` passed to the block following `map` is `` `[0, 4], so ``f => 0, lp1 => 4` and

```
strings[0...4].join(' ') => ["John", "likes", "Hot", "Dogs"] => "John likes Hot Dogs"
```

I initially tried converting `strings` to a string, words separated with a space, and attempted to use a regex, but that was problematic.

- Pun unintended

Comment: I can't say why, but most silent downvotes, as here, bring a smile to my face.